I want to scrape table from pdf file using pypdf or tabula into panda df
How can I scrape data using a Python script with the pypdf or tabula library? Specifically, I need to extract Capital names that are listed in a non-table format from the attached PDF. The desired output should have "India" as the header column and the capital names as rows, which will search across multiple pages. and give different df for different findings.(it might be India > with capital, USA > capital) The condition is to find the specific word "States" and then locate the subsequent "Capital to focus" entries, outputting the results in a DataFrame.
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/kM4UGAup#link
Required output in panda df


Thank you.I have added pdf.I want to search states and capital.
